# Can I use step function as loss function to train Neural Network?

Tags: python, function, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

As title,

I try to build model for predict PM2.5,

It's possible use loss function with gradient decent , such as mse,rmse,mae...etc.

but when I use custom loss function with step function, I seems weights didn't update.

in my model last layers , is output pm2.5 prediction,

and I try to use step function calculate loss

```
def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
  z_true = step_function(y_true)
  z_pred = step_function(y_pred)
  return K.abs(z_true -z_pred)
```

and my step function is try to transform PM2.5 to AQI Levels.

```
def step_function(x):
  step1 = ((K.tanh(x-15.45))+1)/2  # is means PM2.5 <15.45 return 0 >15.45 return 1 
  step2 = ((K.tanh(x-35.45))+1)/2  # is means PM2.5 <35.45 return 0 >35.45 return 1 
  return (step1+step2)  # if x(PM2.5) = 50 , will return 2
```

is possible when y_true and y_pred are equals 0 , and step function return 0 , can't differential
so occur weights did't update?

Comment: have tried `tf.GradientTape()` ?

Comment: No I didn’t know what that

Comment: just to be clear you want to use your custom loss in the model training?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have correctly mentioned, you have to handle Loss when its 0 else there is nothing for optimizer to minimize. Thus weights of the model also won't update. So ideal way in this case is to keep track of `training loss` at `step` level using custom training.

You will have more control with custom training. If you want lower-level over your training and evaluation loops than what `fit()` and `evaluate()` provide, you should write your own training loop. It's actually pretty simple. But you should be ready to have a lot more debugging to do on your own.

Calling a model inside a `GradientTape` scope enables you to retrieve the gradients of the trainable weights of the layer with respect to a loss value. Using an optimizer instance, you can use these gradients to update these variables (which you can retrieve using `model.trainable_weights`).

TensorFlow provides the `tf.GradientTape` API for automatic differentiation - computing the gradient of a computation with respect to its input variables. Tensorflow "records" all operations executed inside the context of a tf.GradientTape onto a "tape". Tensorflow then uses that tape and the gradients associated with each recorded operation to compute the gradients of a "recorded" computation using reverse mode differentiation.

If you want to process the gradients before applying them you can instead use the optimizer in three steps:

1. Compute the gradients with `tf.GradientTape`.
2. Process the gradients as you wish.
3. Apply the processed gradients with `apply_gradients()`.

Here is a simple example for mnist data. The comments are present in the code to explain better.

**Code-**

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# Preprocess the data (these are Numpy arrays)
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype('float32') / 255
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784).astype('float32') / 255

y_train = y_train.astype('float32')
y_test = y_test.astype('float32')

# Reserve 10,000 samples for validation
x_val = x_train[-10000:]
y_val = y_train[-10000:]
x_train = x_train[:-10000]
y_train = y_train[:-10000]

# Get the model.
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,), name='digits')
x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense_1')(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense_2')(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(10, name='predictions')(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

# Instantiate an optimizer.
optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)
# Instantiate a loss function.
loss_fn = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

# Prepare the training dataset.
batch_size = 64
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(batch_size)

epochs = 3
for epoch in range(epochs):
  print('Start of epoch %d' % (epoch,))

  # Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
  for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):

    # Open a GradientTape to record the operations run
    # during the forward pass, which enables autodifferentiation.
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

      # Run the forward pass of the layer.
      # The operations that the layer applies
      # to its inputs are going to be recorded
      # on the GradientTape.
      logits = model(x_batch_train, training=True)  # Logits for this minibatch

      # Compute the loss value for this minibatch.
      loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, logits)

    # Use the gradient tape to automatically retrieve
    # the gradients of the trainable variables with respect to the loss.
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)

    # Run one step of gradient descent by updating
    # the value of the variables to minimize the loss.
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))

    # Log every 200 batches.
    if step % 200 == 0:
        print('Training loss (for one batch) at step %s: %s' % (step, float(loss_value)))
        print('Seen so far: %s samples' % ((step + 1) * 64))
```

**Output -**

```
2.2.0
Start of epoch 0
Training loss (for one batch) at step 0: 2.323657512664795
Seen so far: 64 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 200: 2.3156163692474365
Seen so far: 12864 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 400: 2.2302279472351074
Seen so far: 25664 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 600: 2.131979465484619
Seen so far: 38464 samples
Start of epoch 1
Training loss (for one batch) at step 0: 2.00234317779541
Seen so far: 64 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 200: 1.7992427349090576
Seen so far: 12864 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 400: 1.8583933115005493
Seen so far: 25664 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 600: 1.6005337238311768
Seen so far: 38464 samples
Start of epoch 2
Training loss (for one batch) at step 0: 1.6701987981796265
Seen so far: 64 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 200: 1.6237502098083496
Seen so far: 12864 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 400: 1.3603084087371826
Seen so far: 25664 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 600: 1.246948480606079
Seen so far: 38464 samples
```

You can find more about tf.GradientTape [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#args). The example used here is taken from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate).

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @陳建勤 - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.